# trouble with filtering with checkboxes in angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-pipe

I have a filtered array showing cards of recipes.

in my filter pipe:

```
transform(
    recipes: Recipe[],
    value: string
  ): Recipe[] {
    let resArr = new Set()
    for (let recipe of recipes) {
      if (recipe.title.includes(value)) resArr.add(recipe)
      recipe.ingredients.forEach((ing)=>{
        if(ing.name.includes(value)) resArr.add(recipe)
      })
    }
    return Array.from(resArr) as  Recipe[]
  }
```

in my template:

```
 <div *ngIf="recipesArr | filter: recipeName as recipesArr">
          <div class="d-flex gap-4 flex-wrap">
            <div class="card" *ngFor="let recipe of recipesArr">
              <div (click)="likeRecipe(recipe.recipe_id!)" class="overlay" [ngClass]="{'already-liked': checkIfThisRecipeIsLiked(recipe.recipe_id!)}">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-star mx-3 favorite"></i>
              </div>
              
              <img src="{{ recipe.img }}" class="cardImg" />
              <div class="m-1">
                <div class="card-titles">{{ recipe.title }}</div>
                <div class="card-text small mb-2">
                  <!--You have {{ recipe.ingredients  }} ingredients-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

this code shows all the recipes that match the search successfully.

I'm having trouble doing a **secondary** filter.
I'm trying to further filter the recipesArr array according to the values of the checkboxes (all values are strings).

each recipe has an array of tags (strings) and I would like to show in the search only the recipes that their tag array includes the checkbox returned value

I have tried several approaches for implementing the second filter in another pipe but failed again and again.

is it possible to make a pipe with secondary filter that will instantly reduce the search results according to the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
(I assume that the Recipe model has a field for tags (tagsArray: string[]))

```js
  transform(recipes: Recipe[], searchTerm: string, tags?: string[]): Recipe[] {
    // check null
    if(!recipes?.length || searchTerm == undefined)
      return recipes;
    
    let resArr = []

    // find search term in all fields
    resArr = recipes.filter(res => JSON.stringify(res).includes(searchTerm))

    // filter recipe by tags
    if(tags?.length)
      resArr = resArr.filter(res => {
        for(let tag in tags)
          if(res.tagsArray.includes(tag))
            return true;

        return false
      })

    return resArr
  }
```